# How do i get alert window while the condition not satisfy using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i like to explain my probelm,

i have dropdown call `suminsured_amount`, here i used to get amount like `200000`.
and i have another field call `approved_amount`. now what i need is when i enter a approved amount greater than `suminsured_amount` it automatically populate the `alert window` that you are exceed the `suminsured_amount`, help me to sort out this problem
[image: image1]

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var approved_amount = parseInt($("#importclaims-approved_amount").val(); 
    var suminsured_amount = parseInt($("#importclaims-suminsured_amount").val(); 
    if (approved_amount > suminsured_amount) { 
        alert('exceeded'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: **$(document).ready(function(){
      var approved_amount = parseInt($("#importclaims-approved_amount").val();
      var suminsured_amount = parseInt($("#importclaims-suminsured_amount").val();
        if (approved_amount > suminsured_amount) {
          alert('exceeded');
        }
});'** trying this bt not yet finish

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools' Console. You just made a couple of tiny syntax errors. You have more `(` than you have `)`.

Comment: Your script won't work because it's only related to the ready event. You need to put the condition inside a keydown event

Answer (score 0):

Use the [keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event:

```
//A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.
$("#importclaims-suminsured_amount").on('keydown', function(){
    var suminsured_amount = parseInt($("#importclaims-suminsured_amount").val());
    var approved_amount = parseInt($("#importclaims-approved_amount").val());
    //Condition to alert
    if(suminsured_amount > approved_amount ){
        alert("Exceed the suminsured_amount");
    }

});
```